# How to determine the weights in a neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

If I have a three layer neural network and if I have 3 input samples with their corresponding expected output values, how can I determine the values of the weights along all the edges?

Comment: Use backpropagation for it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation. You can also pack this into a cost function, so you can use a linear optimizer to find good weights.

Comment: if you have less than 20 (binary) weights, you can actually compute them perfectly. (because 2^20 is only a million.) But its hard to get 20 weights to do anything meaningful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estimating the weights of an artificial neural network(ANN) is nothing but a *parametric optimization* problem. In general one needs a *non-linear optimizer* to get the job done. Most cost functions that are optimized in the process are those which penalize the mismatch between the network output and the desired output.

The Backpropagation method is an elegant method of applying gradient based optimization since it enables one to estimate the error at the output of hidden layer neurons. Thus enabling the updation of weights in the hidden layer using error gradients.

To deal with the problem of local minima in gradient based methods it is common practice to use *multi-start methods* which essentially amount to repeating the estimation procedure from a bunch of different initial guesses.

Mind you evolutionary methods such as genetic algorithms also suffer from premature convergence when the population loses diversity.

Also watch out for [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting) the network to the training data. You won't be able to get good generalization for unseen data, which after all is the point of *function approximation* for *predictive learning*.

All this aside what is disconcerting is that the number of training samples is too low to yield much information about the function you are trying to approximate. Loosely speaking if the ANN has a large number of free parameters then the training data must provide enough information to allow for a meaningful estimation of the parameters. 3 samples is just too low for any practical function approximation task.

Comment: Thanks. Brilliant answer. Can you please tell me about overfitting the data? Once the parameters have been found using the gradient descent methods, how do I know if they are all overfit the data?

Comment: You must keep aside some of the data (say, 10%) to be used for testing purposes. Once you have estimated the parameters, test the trained network on this _test data_ set. If the error in testing in large you most certainly have a case of _overfitting_ at hand.

Answer (score 4):

Backpropagation is traditionally used for this. Personally, I have had much better and faster results with the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm.

You also might want to test an evolutionary algorithm (e.g., Genetic Algorithms, Particle Swarm Optimization (easy to implement!)). These are less prone to getting stuck in local optima because they are not based on gradients.

Comment: You should use the backpropagation method to calculate the gradients. Then you can use Levenberg-Marquardt to adjust the weights. Derivative-free algorithms are usually slower.